Why XML File turn into purple code in Swagger? What's Wrong in my code
I'm trying to get an xml request body to display in Swagger UI. However, this is what I get:

This is the documentation I want:
<doc><members> ..... !--5. UpdCom1 -->
    <br>
        <member name="UpdCom1">
            <summary>
                5. 修改賽事資料1-基本資料             </summary>
            <param name="ReqUpdCom1">
                包含 許多比賽其本資料 格式如下：
                
                <br></br>
                <code>TID   [string]</code> - 球隊編號
                
                <br></br>
                <code>CID   [string]</code> - 賽事編號
                
                <br></br>
                <code>CName   [string]</code> - 賽事名稱
                
                <br></br>
                <code>CType   [int]</code> - 賽事類型
                
                <br></br>
                <code>CSubject   [string]</code> - 比賽主旨
                
                <br></br>
                <code>Organizer1   [int]</code> - 主辦單位
                
                <br></br>
                <code>Organizer2   [string]</code> - 承辦單位
                
                <br></br>
                <code>Directed   [int]</code> - 協辦單位
                
                <br></br>
                <code>Co_Organizer   [int]</code> - 協辦單位
                
                <br></br>
                <code>CStartDate   [string]</code> - 賽事開始日期
                
                <br></br>
                <code>CEndDate   [string]</code> - 賽事結束日期
                
                <br></br>
                <code>FID1   [string]</code> - 第1球場編號/名稱
                
                <br></br>
                <code>Fairways1   [int]</code> - 道數1
                
                <br></br>
                <code>FID2   [string]</code> - 第2球場編號/名稱
                
                <br></br>
                <code>Fairways2   [int]</code> - 道數2
                
                <br></br>
                <code>Eligibility   [string]</code> - 參賽資格
                
                <br></br>
                <remarks>
                    <para>Sample Request:</para>
                    <para>POST /Account/ReqUpdCom1</para>
                    <br></br>
                    {
                    <br></br>
                      "tid": "T2000010101",
                    <br></br>
                      "cid": "C2023121100001",
                    <br></br>
                      "cName": "測試比賽A
                    <br></br>
                      "cType": 1
                    <br></br>
                      "cSubject": "Test11
                    <br></br>
                      "organizer1": "Test22",
                    <br></br>
                      "organizer2": "Test33",
                    <br></br>
                      "directed": "Test44",
                    <br></br>
                      "co_Organizer": "Test55",
                    <br></br>
                      "cStartDate": "2023-12-21",
                    <br></br>
                      "cEndDate": "2023-12-22",
                    <br></br>
                      "fiD1": "F0001",
                    <br></br>
                      "fairways1": 12,
                    <br></br>
                      "fiD2": "",
                    <br></br>
                      "fairways2": 0,
                    <br></br>
                      "eligibility": "台北資格"
                    <br></br>
                    }
                    <br></br>
                </remarks>
            </param>
            <returns>返回包含 State狀態 與 訊息</returns>
            <response code="200">
                回傳:
                
                <para>
                    <c>state  [string]</c> - 狀態
                
                </para>
                <para>
                    <c>Msg [string]</c> - 訊息
                
                </para>
                <remarks>
                    <para>
                        <b>Sample Status200 Responses:</b>
                    </para>
                [ 
                    <br></br>
                { 
                    <br></br>
                "state": "OK", 
                    <br></br>
                "msg": "修改成功~" 
                    <br></br>
                } 
                    <br></br>
                ] 
                    <br></br>
                </response>
            </member>
        </members>
    </doc>

Why does it created the all purple block like in the picture? Do I miss something? Feel free to ask any question if there is a doubt, Thanks before
I have anything API that code mostly the same as above but it displaying correctly like below picture (PictureB) As I also want my pictureA code looks like this


Your XML is not well-formed.  To make it well-formed, make the following corrections:

Close the <br> tag.
Close the <remarks> tag.

Here's your XML with the previous corrections applied and with formatting adjustments:
<doc>
  <members> ..... !--5. UpdCom1 -->
    <br></br>
    <member name="UpdCom1">
      <summary>
      5. 修改賽事資料1-基本資料             </summary>
      <param name="ReqUpdCom1">
        包含 許多比賽其本資料 格式如下：
        
        <br></br>
        <code>TID   [string]</code> - 球隊編號
        
        <br></br>
        <code>CID   [string]</code> - 賽事編號
        
        <br></br>
        <code>CName   [string]</code> - 賽事名稱
        
        <br></br>
        <code>CType   [int]</code> - 賽事類型
        
        <br></br>
        <code>CSubject   [string]</code> - 比賽主旨
        
        <br></br>
        <code>Organizer1   [int]</code> - 主辦單位
        
        <br></br>
        <code>Organizer2   [string]</code> - 承辦單位
        
        <br></br>
        <code>Directed   [int]</code> - 協辦單位
        
        <br></br>
        <code>Co_Organizer   [int]</code> - 協辦單位
        
        <br></br>
        <code>CStartDate   [string]</code> - 賽事開始日期
        
        <br></br>
        <code>CEndDate   [string]</code> - 賽事結束日期
        
        <br></br>
        <code>FID1   [string]</code> - 第1球場編號/名稱
        
        <br></br>
        <code>Fairways1   [int]</code> - 道數1
        
        <br></br>
        <code>FID2   [string]</code> - 第2球場編號/名稱
        
        <br></br>
        <code>Fairways2   [int]</code> - 道數2
        
        <br></br>
        <code>Eligibility   [string]</code> - 參賽資格
        
        <br></br>
        <remarks>
          <para>Sample Request:</para>
          <para>POST /Account/ReqUpdCom1</para>
          <br></br>
          {
          <br></br>
          "tid": "T2000010101",
          <br></br>
          "cid": "C2023121100001",
          <br></br>
          "cName": "測試比賽A
          <br></br>
          "cType": 1
          <br></br>
          "cSubject": "Test11
          <br></br>
          "organizer1": "Test22",
          <br></br>
          "organizer2": "Test33",
          <br></br>
          "directed": "Test44",
          <br></br>
          "co_Organizer": "Test55",
          <br></br>
          "cStartDate": "2023-12-21",
          <br></br>
          "cEndDate": "2023-12-22",
          <br></br>
          "fiD1": "F0001",
          <br></br>
          "fairways1": 12,
          <br></br>
          "fiD2": "",
          <br></br>
          "fairways2": 0,
          <br></br>
          "eligibility": "台北資格"
          <br></br>
          }
          <br></br>
        </remarks>
      </param>
      <returns>返回包含 State狀態 與 訊息</returns>
      <response code="200">
        回傳:
        
        <para>
          <c>state  [string]</c> - 狀態
          
        </para>
        <para>
          <c>Msg [string]</c> - 訊息
          
        </para>
        <remarks>
          <para>
            <b>Sample Status200 Responses:</b>
          </para>
          [ 
          <br></br>
          { 
          <br></br>
          "state": "OK", 
          <br></br>
          "msg": "修改成功~" 
          <br></br>
          } 
          <br></br>
          ] 
          <br></br>
        </remarks>
      </response>
    </member>
  </members>
</doc>

If your application is sensitive to the indentation adjustments, then ignore this reformatted version of your XML and apply the described corrections directly to your copy as-is to correct the well-formedness problems alone.
